# Password RegEx - not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a RegEx for a password that must contain:

- at least one uppercase character
- at least one lowercase character
- at least one digit
- at least one symbol character out of:  `~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]|:;"'<>,.?/ and the space character
- should have a minimum length of 6 ch.

So far I came up with this:

```
^\S*(?=\S{6,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)([`\~\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+={}\[\]\|:;"'<>,\.\?\/ ])\S*$
```

But for some reason it's not working as I hoped. I've always had trouble with these things, so any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not very expressible as a single regexp. As you've tagged "javascript", here's how I'd do it in JS.

```
function validatePassword(password) {
  return password.length >= 6 &&
    /[A-Z]/.exec(password) &&
    /[a-z]/.exec(password) &&
    /[0-9]/.exec(password) &&
    /[ `~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}\[\]|:;"'<>,.?\/]/.exec(password);
}
```

Comment: I think the only way to do it with one regex would be a huge monster... You'd have to check for all groups in every possible order and even then the length check would be hard to impossible

Comment: I tried it out and got this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[ `~!@#$%^&*()_-+={}\[\]|:;"'<>,.?\/]/:Range out of order in character class

Comment: Alright, it's done. I had to escape some characters in order for it to work. **.^$*+?()[]{\|-** - these ones. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that @Kapn0batai, didn't really check the regexp too much.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[`\~\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+={}\[\]\|:;"'<>,\.\?\/ ]).{6,}/;
```

The full explanation how i did this is on [art of web website](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate-password/#.UZ3fhLWSLFg)

Comment: Hmm lookaheads, this is an interesting solution, but i think it is very expensive, because of lots of backtracking.

Comment: @MofX the only way is to test it :)

Comment: What I just realized, you overescaped the group with the symbols. The only things that needs to be escaped are ] and /. I'm not sure how the regexp implementations behave if symbols are escaped that have no other meaning.